# Update XML with python script

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

We have a big XML for order and we have to parse it. Some of the order attributes coming as `<custom-attribute attribute-id="attibute-id">some value</custom-attribute>`. We are parsing this XML through SSIS and it's having issue retrieving value of these attributes. We noticed that if we add a value, it works `<custom-attribute attribute-id="attibute-id"><value>some value</value></custom-attribute>`

So, before parsing the XML using SSIS, is there any way we add `<value>` tag on all `<custom-attribute>` elements as shown below using python:

Current XML:

```
<custom-attributes>
       <custom-attribute attribute-id="color">BLACK</custom-attribute>
       <custom-attribute attribute-id="colorDesc">BLACK</custom-attribute>            
</custom-attributes>
```

Transformed XML:

```
<custom-attributes>
           <custom-attribute attribute-id="color">
            <value>BLACK</value>
            </custom-attribute>
           <custom-attribute attribute-id="colorDesc">
           <value>BLACK</value>
          </custom-attribute>            
    </custom-attributes>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can parse XML and add SubElement to XML. Let's say that you have XML data in file named "SomeData.xml":

```
<custom-attributes>
       <custom-attribute attribute-id="color">BLACK</custom-attribute>
       <custom-attribute attribute-id="colorDesc">BLACK</custom-attribute>            
</custom-attributes>
```

You can convert this file with next Python script:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

XML = ET.parse('SomeData.xml').getroot()

for Atr in XML.findall('custom-attribute'): # Foreach 'custom-attribute' in root

    Val = ET.SubElement(Atr, "value") # Create new XML SubElement named 'value'
    Val.text = Atr.text               # Write text from parent to child element
    Atr.text = ""                     # Clear parent text

ET.ElementTree(XML).write("Output.xml")
```

Which generates desired XML and it saves it as "Output.xml":

```
<custom-attributes>
       <custom-attribute attribute-id="color"><value>BLACK</value></custom-attribute>
       <custom-attribute attribute-id="colorDesc"><value>BLACK</value></custom-attribute>            
</custom-attributes>
```

Hope it helps!